# How to access an object key from a list in the render?

Tags: arrays, object, dart, flutter, key

I'm new to dart and I'm trying to access a key from an object that is in a list. I might be wrong but I'm always getting type error saying that `name` isn't defined for the class object.

This is my list.

```
  List<Object> _nbaPlayerList = [
    {
    "name": "Lebron James",
    "pts": 27.2,
    "assist": 7.4,
    "rebound":7.4,
    "fg%":50.4
    },
    {
    "name": "Kevin Durant",
    "pts": 27.1,
    "assist": 4.1,
    "rebound":7.1,
    "fg%":49.2
    },
  ];
```

This is what i'm trying to render

```
Column(children: _nbaPlayerList
 .map((element ) => 
   Card(
    child: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Image.asset("assets/lebron_james.jpg"),
        Text(element.name)
       ],
      ),
     ),
    ).toList(),
   ),
```

How can I acces the name key in my array object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a slight change of the type in your list, change it to:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> _nbaPlayerList
```

In dart, JSON can be represented with a map between String and dynamic. So now you have a list with JSON and can access the fields like this:

```
element["name"]
```